# Failed to install ghcjs-dom-0.0.7 - src/GHCJS/DOM.hs:3:14: Unsupported extension: JavaScriptFFI

Tags: haskell, gtk, ghc, cabal, ghcjs

I have problems installing Leksah, the depends on ghcjs-dom:

Here's what I precisely get when trying to install this precise package:

```
$ cabal install ghcjs-dom -v
Reading available packages...
Choosing modular solver.
Resolving dependencies...
Ready to install ghcjs-dom-0.0.7
Waiting for install task to finish...
Extracting
/Users/bastiengallay/Library/Haskell/repo-cache/hackage.haskell.org/ghcjs-dom/0.0.7/ghcjs-dom-0.0.7.tar.gz
to /var/folders/1s/mnr_nf9x1c3fr5v_bcrg712m0000gn/T/ghcjs-dom-0.0.7-24896...
Updating ghcjs-dom.cabal with the latest revision from the index.
Configuring ghcjs-dom-0.0.7...
Flags chosen: gtk3=True, jsc=False, webkit=False, jsffi=False, ghcjs=True
Dependency base ==4.6.0.1: using base-4.6.0.1
Dependency mtl ==2.2.0.1: using mtl-2.2.0.1
Using Cabal-1.20.0.0 compiled by ghc-7.6
Using compiler: ghc-7.6.3
Using install prefix:
/Users/bastiengallay/Library/Haskell/ghc-7.6.3/lib/ghcjs-dom-0.0.7
Binaries installed in:
/Users/bastiengallay/Library/Haskell/ghc-7.6.3/lib/ghcjs-dom-0.0.7/bin
Libraries installed in:
/Users/bastiengallay/Library/Haskell/ghc-7.6.3/lib/ghcjs-dom-0.0.7/lib
Private binaries installed in:
/Users/bastiengallay/Library/Haskell/ghc-7.6.3/lib/ghcjs-dom-0.0.7/libexec
Data files installed in:
/Users/bastiengallay/Library/Haskell/ghc-7.6.3/lib/ghcjs-dom-0.0.7/share
Documentation installed in:
/Users/bastiengallay/Library/Haskell/ghc-7.6.3/lib/ghcjs-dom-0.0.7/doc
Configuration files installed in:
/Users/bastiengallay/Library/Haskell/ghc-7.6.3/lib/ghcjs-dom-0.0.7/etc
Using alex version 3.1.3 found on system at:
/Users/bastiengallay/Library/Haskell/bin/alex
Using ar found on system at: /usr/bin/ar
No c2hs found
No cpphs found
No ffihugs found
Using gcc version 4.8.3 found on system at: /usr/local/bin/gcc
Using ghc version 7.6.3 found on system at: /usr/local/bin/ghc
Using ghc-pkg version 7.6.3 found on system at: /usr/local/bin/ghc-pkg
No greencard found
Using haddock version 2.13.2 found on system at: /usr/local/bin/haddock
Using happy version 1.19.3 found on system at:
/Users/bastiengallay/Library/Haskell/bin/happy
Using haskell-suite found on system at: haskell-suite-dummy-location
Using haskell-suite-pkg found on system at: haskell-suite-pkg-dummy-location
No hmake found
Using hpc version 0.6 found on system at: /usr/local/bin/hpc
Using hsc2hs version 0.67 found on system at: /usr/local/bin/hsc2hs
No hscolour found
No hugs found
No jhc found
Using ld found on system at: /usr/bin/ld
No lhc found
No lhc-pkg found
No nhc98 found
Using pkg-config version 0.28 found on system at: /usr/local/bin/pkg-config
Using strip found on system at: /usr/bin/strip
Using tar found on system at: /usr/bin/tar
No uhc found
Component build order: library
creating dist/build
creating dist/build/autogen
Building ghcjs-dom-0.0.7...
Preprocessing library ghcjs-dom-0.0.7...
Building library...
creating dist/build
/usr/local/bin/ghc --make -fbuilding-cabal-package -O -outputdir dist/build -odir dist/build -hidir dist/build -stubdir dist/build -i -idist/build -isrc -idist/build/autogen -Idist/build/autogen -Idist/build -optP-include -optPdist/build/autogen/cabal_macros.h -package-name ghcjs-dom-0.0.7 -hide-all-packages -package-db dist/package.conf.inplace -package-id base-4.6.0.1-6c351d70a24d3e96f315cba68f3acf57 -package-id mtl-2.2.0.1-ef91e0abcf7a4fb581ecb7fe83cdcba1 -XHaskell2010 GHCJS.DOM GHCJS.DOM.Types GHCJS.DOM.Attr GHCJS.DOM.BarProp GHCJS.DOM.Blob GHCJS.DOM.CharacterData GHCJS.DOM.Console GHCJS.DOM.Css GHCJS.DOM.CSSRule GHCJS.DOM.CSSRuleList GHCJS.DOM.CSSStyleDeclaration GHCJS.DOM.CSSStyleSheet GHCJS.DOM.CSSValue GHCJS.DOM.Document GHCJS.DOM.DocumentType GHCJS.DOM.DOMApplicationCache GHCJS.DOM.DOMImplementation GHCJS.DOM.DOMMimeType GHCJS.DOM.DOMMimeTypeArray GHCJS.DOM.DOMNamedFlowCollection GHCJS.DOM.DOMPlugin GHCJS.DOM.DOMPluginArray GHCJS.DOM.DOMSelection GHCJS.DOM.DOMSettableTokenList GHCJS.DOM.DOMTokenList GHCJS.DOM.DOMWindow GHCJS.DOM.DOMWindowCSS GHCJS.DOM.Element GHCJS.DOM.Event GHCJS.DOM.EventM GHCJS.DOM.Events GHCJS.DOM.EventTargetClosures GHCJS.DOM.File GHCJS.DOM.FileList GHCJS.DOM.History GHCJS.DOM.HTMLAnchorElement GHCJS.DOM.HTMLAppletElement GHCJS.DOM.HTMLAreaElement GHCJS.DOM.HTMLBaseElement GHCJS.DOM.HTMLBaseFontElement GHCJS.DOM.HTMLBodyElement GHCJS.DOM.HTMLBRElement GHCJS.DOM.HTMLButtonElement GHCJS.DOM.HTMLCollection GHCJS.DOM.HTMLDirectoryElement GHCJS.DOM.HTMLDivElement GHCJS.DOM.HTMLDListElement GHCJS.DOM.HTMLDocument GHCJS.DOM.HTMLElement GHCJS.DOM.HTMLFieldSetElement GHCJS.DOM.HTMLFontElement GHCJS.DOM.HTMLFormElement GHCJS.DOM.HTMLFrameElement GHCJS.DOM.HTMLFrameSetElement GHCJS.DOM.HTMLHeadElement GHCJS.DOM.HTMLHeadingElement GHCJS.DOM.HTMLHRElement GHCJS.DOM.HTMLHtmlElement GHCJS.DOM.HTMLIFrameElement GHCJS.DOM.HTMLImageElement GHCJS.DOM.HTMLInputElement GHCJS.DOM.HTMLLabelElement GHCJS.DOM.HTMLLegendElement GHCJS.DOM.HTMLLIElement GHCJS.DOM.HTMLLinkElement GHCJS.DOM.HTMLMapElement GHCJS.DOM.HTMLMenuElement GHCJS.DOM.HTMLMetaElement GHCJS.DOM.HTMLModElement GHCJS.DOM.HTMLObjectElement GHCJS.DOM.HTMLOListElement GHCJS.DOM.HTMLOptGroupElement GHCJS.DOM.HTMLOptionElement GHCJS.DOM.HTMLOptionsCollection GHCJS.DOM.HTMLParagraphElement GHCJS.DOM.HTMLParamElement GHCJS.DOM.HTMLPreElement GHCJS.DOM.HTMLQuoteElement GHCJS.DOM.HTMLScriptElement GHCJS.DOM.HTMLSelectElement GHCJS.DOM.HTMLStyleElement GHCJS.DOM.HTMLTableCaptionElement GHCJS.DOM.HTMLTableCellElement GHCJS.DOM.HTMLTableColElement GHCJS.DOM.HTMLTableElement GHCJS.DOM.HTMLTableRowElement GHCJS.DOM.HTMLTableSectionElement GHCJS.DOM.HTMLTextAreaElement GHCJS.DOM.HTMLTitleElement GHCJS.DOM.HTMLUListElement GHCJS.DOM.KeyboardEvent GHCJS.DOM.Location GHCJS.DOM.MediaList GHCJS.DOM.MediaQueryList GHCJS.DOM.MouseEvent GHCJS.DOM.NamedNodeMap GHCJS.DOM.Navigator GHCJS.DOM.Node GHCJS.DOM.NodeFilter GHCJS.DOM.NodeIterator GHCJS.DOM.NodeList GHCJS.DOM.ProcessingInstruction GHCJS.DOM.Range GHCJS.DOM.Ranges GHCJS.DOM.Screen GHCJS.DOM.StyleMedia GHCJS.DOM.StyleSheet GHCJS.DOM.StyleSheetList GHCJS.DOM.Stylesheets GHCJS.DOM.Storage GHCJS.DOM.Text GHCJS.DOM.Traversal GHCJS.DOM.TreeWalker GHCJS.DOM.UIEvent GHCJS.DOM.ValidityState GHCJS.DOM.WebKitNamedFlow GHCJS.DOM.WebKitPoint GHCJS.DOM.XPathExpression GHCJS.DOM.XPathNSResolver GHCJS.DOM.XPathResult GHCJS.DOM.DOMSecurityPolicy GHCJS.DOM.DOMStringList GHCJS.DOM.Geolocation GHCJS.DOM.HTMLCanvasElement GHCJS.DOM.HTMLDetailsElement GHCJS.DOM.HTMLEmbedElement GHCJS.DOM.HTMLKeygenElement GHCJS.DOM.HTMLMarqueeElement GHCJS.DOM.HTMLMediaElement GHCJS.DOM.HTMLVideoElement GHCJS.DOM.MediaError GHCJS.DOM.StorageInfo GHCJS.DOM.TimeRanges

src/GHCJS/DOM.hs:3:14: Unsupported extension: JavaScriptFFI
Failed to install ghcjs-dom-0.0.7
World file is already up to date.
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
ghcjs-dom-0.0.7 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
```

My config:

```
$ cabal --version
cabal-install version 1.20.0.2
using version 1.20.0.0 of the Cabal library
$ ghc --version
The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 7.6.3
```

Some patches seem to exist for GHC 7.8, but don't know how to use them.

Comment: My understand is you need to be using ghcjs but it looks like the ghc which is being run is the vanilla ghc.

Comment: I'm using this ghc in ordre to prevent a problem with XCode 5 / XCode 4.6 cohabitation : https://github.com/darinmorrison/homebrew-haskell

Answer (score 1):

ghcjs-dom is not designed to be installed with ghc, it is designed to be installed with ghc-js. To install packages for ghc-js, you need to run `cabal install --ghcjs packageName`

Answer (score 0):

I noticed in the error messages that "c2hs" can't be found.  This is often caused by not having ~/.cabal/bin in your path.  Try typing "c2hs" at the prompt, this will tell you if it is set up.

Comment: That didn't solve the problem, even if you are right : c2hs wasn't installed. Even after installation of c2hs, the problem remains.
About `~/.cabal/bin` for some reason, on my mac the equivalent is `~/Library/Haskell/bin`